# Javascript onclick event for div tag

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, dom-events

I have the following div tag: (jobform)

```
<!--jobform-->
<div class="jobform" onclick="SetChecks();">
<div class="jobform_l" ><?php _e('Category');?> : <span class="required">*</span>      </div>
 
<div class="jobform_r" > 
 
<?php require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/jobs_category.php');?>
</div>
<div class="aglabel">Job Poster :</div>
</div><!--jobform-->
```

I am generating an array of checkboxes (Categories), since I don't have the checkbox tags I will need to capture the event of `onclick` on this div and check/uncheck certain checkboxes. Like when one is checked I want the other one to be unchecked. So I have implemented the following Javascript to do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function SetChecks() { 
Alert("test");
if(document.getElementById('41').Checked)
{
document.getElementById('39').Checked = false;
}
else if(document.getElementById('39').Checked)
{
document.getElementById('41').Checked = false;
}
</script>
```

But for some reason it is not being triggered, I event tried putting an  `Alert()` just to make sure it is being clicked or no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, `alert()` has to be in lowercase in order to work.

Comment: If your answer was the solution, you should mark it as the solution. This will aid others that look for unsolved questions, and it will increase your reputation.

Comment: @bakoyaro Really, even I dont know how to do it, please let me too, Thanks :)

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri If there is an outline of a check mark near the score of an answer on one of your questions, then you would be able to mark it as accepted. See the FAQ for more info

Comment: I had to wait 24 hours to accept my own solution. I could not do it right away.

Answer (score 1):

The property is `checked`, not `Checked`. JavaScript is case sensitive (*unlike* some of PHP).

In addition, a valid`id` attribute can not start with a number.

Comment: These categories are wordpress categories, when I got to the editing page of category I see the "tag_ID=41" in the URL so I assume the ID for that checkbox is 41. But since I need to perform this on 2 known checkboxes I know their names too. Will I be able to check/uncheck them with names?

Comment: by the way it's not even triggering that onclick cuz I got an alert() there